# Error while installing EasyOCR on windows

Tags: python, ocr, python-wheel

On running `pip install easyocr` in windows terminal in administrator mode. Gives the following output:

> Collecting easyocr Using cached easyocr-1.0.tar.gz (8.5 MB) WARNING:
> The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version:
> 'torch' candidate (version 0.1.2.post2 at
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz#sha256=a43e37f8f927c5b18f80cd163daaf6a1920edafcab5102e02e3e14bb97d9c874
> (from https://pypi.org/simple/torch/)) Reason for being yanked: 0.1.2
> is past it's support date and confuses users on unsupported platforms
> Collecting torch Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB) ERROR:
> Command errored out with exit status 1: command:
> 'c:\python27\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize;
> sys.argv[0] =
> '"'"'c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7vcyae\torch\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7vcyae\torch\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> egg_info --egg-base
> 'c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-pip-egg-info-trszn4' cwd:
> c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7vcyae\torch
> Complete output (8 lines): Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "", line 1, in  File
> "c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-7vcyae\torch\setup.py",
> line 147, in  import numpy as np File "C:\Users\Khush
> Kalavadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py",
> line 132 raise ImportError(msg) from e ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full
> command output.

On running `pip install easyocr` in Visual Studio Code. Gives the following output:

> Collecting easyocr   Using cached easyocr-1.0.tar.gz (8.5 MB) WARNING:
> The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version:
> 'torch' candidate (version 0.1.2.post2 at
> https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f8/02/880b468bd382dc79896eaecbeb8ce95e9c4b99a24902874a2cef0b562cea/torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz#sha256=a43e37f8f927c5b18f80cd163daaf6a1920edafcab5102e02e3e14bb97d9c874
> (from https://pypi.org/simple/torch/)) Reason for being yanked: 0.1.2
> is past it's support date and confuses users on unsupported platforms
> Collecting torch   Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
> Collecting torchvision   Using cached
> torchvision-0.2.2.post3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB) Collecting
> opencv-python   Using cached opencv-python-4.3.0.38.tar.gz (88.0 MB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done   Getting requirements to build
> wheel ... error   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'c:\python27\python.exe'
> 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py'
> get_requires_for_build_wheel
> 'c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgrhqfp'
> cwd: c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-6wppb1\opencv-python
> Complete output (22 lines):   Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
> line 280, in 
> main()
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
> line 263, in main
> json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
> File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py",
> line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return hook(config_settings)
> File "c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-iff1we\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 146, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
> return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
> File "c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-iff1we\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 127, in _get_build_requires
> self.run_setup()
> File "c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-iff1we\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 243, in run_setup
> self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
> File "c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-iff1we\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
> exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'), locals())
> File "setup.py", line 448, in 
> main()
> File "setup.py", line 99, in main
> % {"ext": re.escape(sysconfig.get_config_var("EXT_SUFFIX"))}
> File "c:\python27\lib\re.py", line 210, in escape
> s = list(pattern)   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable   ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python27\python.exe'
> 'c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517_in_process.py'
> get_requires_for_build_wheel
> 'c:\users\khushk~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgrhqfp' Check the logs for
> full command output.

Comment: I guess there are some problems with the Python version. Currently you have Python 2.7 installed which is no longer supported. The errors you receive are originating from the Python 3 syntax used in one of the libraries which is incompatible with the Python 2 installed on your system. Try to install one of the latest Python interpreters (3.8 or 3.9) and use it in your project.